# Checking if point is inside the mesh via raycasting - where to cast rays?

Tags: voxels, raycasting, mesh

I need to voxelize triangle meshes which involves testing if a point is located inside or outside the given mesh.
I have just implemented a basic algo based on raycasting and checking the number of ray-mesh intersections (by intersecting the ray with each triangle).

I select a position which lies outside the mesh: I add a small offset to the mesh's bounding box.
Then I cast a ray from the point being tested to the position calculated above.

1) How to find the position which definitely lies inside or outside the mesh?
What are good values for the 'offset' which is added to the mesh's bounds?
(Currently, I'm using offset = vec3(1,1,1).)

2) The method is very slow. For example, voxelizing "cow.ply" (17412 vertices, 5804 triangles) on a 128^3 grid takes almost 5 minutes on a 3 GHz CPU!
What is a good acceleration strategy? (I plan to add a uniform grid where each cell keeps indices to intersecting triangles.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of calculations can be simplified by turning this into a 2D problem, and you can do that by casting your ray along a single axis -- x, y, or z.

For a given V = { Vx, Vy, Vz }, if we cast our ray along the z axis, we're effectively just checking which triangles intersect the 2D point V2 = { Vx, Vy } (projected into 2D by removing the z component). From there, find the z value for the point of intersection of V with each triangle. Count the number of triangles whose z-point of intersection is greater than Vz (we're effectively doing a ray trace in the positive z direction). If it's even, V is outside the mesh; if it's odd, it's inside the mesh (assuming the mesh is closed).

This leads to the main optimization:
**Rasterise the triangles into a 2D grid.**

That is, you'll want to pre-calculate which triangles intersect which 2D { x, y } points in your grid, and with what z value, because that way you're only calculating triangle intersections for 128^2 points instead of 128^3 points. This can be done by rasterising the triangles to a 2D 128^2 grid, but keeping a list of intersecting triangles or z points of intersection for each point in the grid. The 2D grid could be anything from a 2D array of arrays to something more space-efficient, but I think that's beyond the scope of this question.